What value should I assign to kernel.exec-shield
I am setting up my own web server at home using Ubuntu 22.04 and trying to understand a setting. I am trying to learn about securing/hardening the system and I am getting a little confused about a setting in the sysctl.conf file.
I understand that it is a good idea to secure the kernel.exec-shield setting and see that it can be assigned four different values: 0-3.
I can understand that 0 always disables it while 3 always enables it. I am just a little confused about setting it to either 1 or 2. I have seen that it should be used along with kernel.randomize_va_space
From my research, I have seen that both should be set to 1. Going through the /etc/sysctl.conf file, it says to set both to either 1 0r 2. Setting it to 1 disables it except binaries that enable it while 2 enables it except binaries that disable it.
So, what I would like to know is shouldn't both be set to 2?
If someone could please explain if I should set both to 1 or 2 and why I should do this.

The Exec-Shield can no longer be managed via sysctl, it is enabled by default with no option to disable. In older systems the kernel.exec-shield key had a value of 1 to enable it and 0 to disable it. To know if your CPU support NX protection you could do

grep -Fw nx /proc/cpuinfo

and watch for nx in flags.
If your CPU has the NX feature you don't have do do nothing. Exec-Shield is for NX emulation in the kernel. You should read this about Non-Executable Memory in Ubuntu.The randomize_va_space controls Address Space Layout Randomization (ASLR) that is used in preventing exploitation of memory corruption vulnerabilities like buffer overflow attacks. There is a little old but good article that explains this.If you want to know all the Ubuntu security features there is a Matrix with them.

Thanks for the info. I was curious because when I was looking at my sysctl.conf file it contained the following in it:                                                                                         #Enable ExecShield protection
#Set value to 1 or 2 (recommended)
#kernel.exec-shield = 2
#kernel.randomize_va_space=2
This is what got me a little confused. If it is not managed by sysctl, why would they have this in the .conf file. Sorry for my misunderstanding of the whole situation. I am fairly new to this and trying to learn.

after running the above command, it does list NX as one of the flags.

@kerinism1 I edited my answer with more information.
